# Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to BufferedImage

Tags: java, android, image, bufferedimage, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a ByteArrayOutputStream I have created using the `QRGen Qr code generation library`, and I want to turn it into a `BufferedImage` object and present it in an ImageView in Android. How may that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the ByteArrayOutputStream to Byte array

```
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray(); //baos is your ByteArrayOutputStream object
```

them create a bitmap out of it using the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (data,0,data.length, null);
```

them take your [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) and set its bitmap

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```